# I get "file not found: example.java" and I placed my file in jre/bin

Tags: java, windows

Please help me compile and execute my program.

I had written a basic hello program in java jdk1.8.0_221 and on Compilation it's giving an error "file not found" example.java Please help me in compiling the program.

Comment: `cd /folder/where/example.java/resides && javac example.java`

Comment: We need details. What command did you use to compile the program? What does the file system look like. Why did you put your file in `jre/bin`?

Comment: Where is your file located?

Answer (score 0):

Any Java class can be everywhere in your file system, preferably not in a spaced-path, and shouldn't be in JRE/bin directory. 
To compile a class, use the command prompt to go to the owning directory use command javac className.java